# Enabling SSLv3 in Weblogic 12

Tags: ssl, java, weblogic, poodle

Yes, I know this is generally a bad idea, but we have a short-term need to do it.

Following this:
https://docs.oracle.com/middleware/1221/wls/SECMG/ssl_version.htm#SECMG637

We have set

```
-Dweblogic.security.SSL.minimumProtocolVersion=SSLv3 (originally set to TLSv1.2)
-Dweblogic.security.SSL.protocolVersion=ALL
```

(the second shouldn't be needed, but should also be harmless)

This didn't work. According to this: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/guides/security/SunProviders.html#enable-sslv3

JDK8 doesn't support SSLv3 out of the box, but can be enabled by:

> If SSLv3 is absolutely required, the protocol can be reactivated at
>   JRE level by removing "SSLv3" from the jdk.tls.disabledAlgorithms
>   property in the java.security file or by dynamically setting this
>   Security property before JSSE is initialized.
>
> To enable SSLv3 protocol at deploy level, after following the above
>   steps, edit the deployment.properties file and add the following:
>
> deployment.security.SSLv3=true

We've done the first of these changes, but it's not clear what "enable... at deploy level" means for Weblogic, and we can't find a deployment.properties file.

Do we need to do this step? And if so, where is the deployment.properties file (or equivalent) for weblogic?

Alternatively, has anyone successfully re-enabled SSLv3 support in Weblogic 12 and can tell us what needs to be changed?

ue

Answer (score 0):

Answering my own question, as we just did some tests:

> Do we need to do this step?

No. The changes to the startup args and java.security files are enough

SSLv3 is working again - the ServerFault cardboard-cutout programmer works again